# How do I use an alternative version of mysql with Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2

My production server is running MySql 5.6.

If I use `brew install` on my local machine I get version 8.0, which is not compatible with data from MySql 5.6.

So I completely uninstalled mysql and ran `brew install mysql@5.6` and then prepended `/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin` to my path.

The problem is that the rails' mysql2 gem will not function without running the standard `brew install mysql` because it cannot find some file.

Any suggestions of how to run with an older version of mysql?

Comment: "Some file"? Set up the library load path correctly? Without knowing what the actual error is not sure how to actually help.

Comment: if you have the path to the version of mysql you can install the gem with '--with-mysql-dir='. Documentation can be found here https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2. You may also be able to solve this with "set global sql_mode = '' " and "set session sql_mode = '' " (setting the sql_mode can cause differences between local and production that will be very hard to debug)